# Pipe UDP input to FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, udp, rtp

A video camera is sending me video data as RTPs via UDP on a local port.

Does ffmpeg support automatically conversion of input (H.264 payload) to MP4 ?

How to do that ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work:

```
ffmpeg -i udp://localhost:1234 -vcodec copy output.mp4
```

Or try:

```
ffmpeg -i rtp://localhost:1234 -vcodec copy output.mp4
```

Replace 1234 with your port. I assume that the input is already in H.264, if not, remove the -vcodec copy.

Comment: be careful with this one, when receiving udp packets, if the source stops sending them, then ffmpeg will stall. if you try to CTRL+C it, then it'll result in unplayable mp4 file

Comment: I posted question about difference between UDP and RTP http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27930879/what-is-ffmpegs-udp-protocol