# Android and Nginx Rtmp Module solution

Tags: android, nginx, video-streaming, rtmp, wowza

folks

I have an Android app that streams videos to Wowza Server. Right now, I am using libstreaming (https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming) in the Android app to livestream audio and video to Wowza.

It works fine, but I am building an open source solution and I would like to stop using Wowza (since it is a payed product) and start using nginx-rtmp-module (https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module). The problem is that libstreaming does not work with rtmp protocol, and, as much as I researched, I still couldn't find a good solution on the Android side to livestream to nginx.

Does anybody know any solution to do that? Did anybody already implemented it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use ffmpeg to convert RTP into RTMP on server side.
e.g. [Pipe UDP input to FFMPEG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12003014/pipe-udp-input-to-ffmpeg)

Comment: Thank you, @rshmelev. But how can I make this work in a production server where I receive several dynamic streams with different names, all to be saved in the server. BTW, also to be watched from JWPlayer in browsers live.